# Azure AD: getting Invalid X509 certificate chain when Unbind with itfoxtec

Tags: azure-active-directory, adfs, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am using Azure AD as ADFS and I get response from it in the ACS route, however I am getting:

AuthenticationException: Invalid X509 certificate chain. Certificate name:'CN=accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net' and thumbprint:'9CEA376***********251D1F*****'. Chain Status:'A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.'..

When running: binding.Unbind(httpRequest, saml2AuthnResponse);
Note that same Saml2Configuration was done in the request and in the response.

any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the chain to validate successfully. The certificates root certificate has to be installed on the machine as a trusted root certificate. This is not possible in e.g. a Azure App Service.

The check kan be disabled by configuring `"CertificateValidationMode": "None"` in `appsettings.json`.
Sample code:  https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/appsettings.json#L19

Comment: Can you please tell me what does the .unbind() do?

Comment: The unbind do the same as read and then it validates the received SAML 2.0 request / response including signatur validation.