# OKTA: getting Invalid X509 certificate chain when Unbind with itfoxtec

Tags: .net-6.0, okta, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am using OKTA as IDP. I am getting error on [the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqbt3.png)

[Azure AD: getting Invalid X509 certificate chain when Unbind with itfoxtec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72812266/azure-ad-getting-invalid-x509-certificate-chain-when-unbind-with-itfoxtec/76184928#76184928)

I found this article and I have the same issue, but my IDP is OKTA. How can I obtain the root certificate for OKTA?

I cannot use "CertificateValidationMode": "None" because the Checkmarx code scan indicates that it is unsafe.

Therefore, I must obtain the root certificate to resolve this issue.

Please help me, as I have been stuck for several days.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Okta's SAML certificates are usually self-signed ones. So it's the same certificate which you are getting when configuring SSO in Okta with a SAML app. It's a part of IdP's metadata also.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, so what should I do next?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem, and the steps are as follows:

1. Save the X509Certificate from the IDP Metadata as a .crt file.
2. Import the .crt file into the root certificates of the SP.

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable the certificate validation to enable self-signed certificates.

In config set `"CertificateValidationMode": "None"` and `"RevocationMode": "NoCheck"`.
Shown in the ASP.NET Core [sample application](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/appsettings.json#L19).